# Dijkstra SSSP with blocked path

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path, dijkstra

I was working on this problem and I decided to use Dijkstra's algorithm to solve it. However, I am unsure of how to account for the blocked path from a to b and how to account for the waiting time of 60 minutes when the path is blocked. Do I need more than one SSSP to solve this problem? How can I approach solving this problem?

[image]

Image credits: National University of Singapore

My code is as follows:

```
struct road_tuples{
    int u;
    int v;
    int w;
};

int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[], int V){
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int min_index;
    for(int v = 0; v<V;v++){
        if(sptSet[v]==false && dist[v]<=min){
            min = dist[v];
            min_index  = v;
        }
    }
    return min_index;
}
//dijkstra using adj matrix
int minMinutes(int V, int a, int b, int c, int d, int E, road_tuples list){
    //create adjacency matrix
    int graph[V][V];
    //fill in adjacency matrix
    for(int i=0;i<E;i++)
        graph[list.u][list.v] = list.w;
        graph[list.v][list.u] = list.w;
    //no path from a to b
    graph[a][b] = 0;
    graph[b][a] = 0;
    //assign source
    int src = c;
    //will hold shortest distance from src to i
    int dist[V];
    //sptSet[i] will be true if i included in SSSP
    bool sptSet[V];
    //init all distances to infinite, set sptSet[i] as false
    for(int i =0; i < V; i++){
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
        sptSet[i] = false;
    }
    //set dist from source to itself as 0
    dist[src] = 0;
    //find shortest path for all vertices
    for(int count =0; count< V-1; count++){
        int u  = minDistance(dist, sptSet, V);
        sptSet[u] = true;
        for(int v=0; v<V; v++){
            if(!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u]!= INT_MAX
               && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
        }
    }

    return dist[d];
}
```

Comment: One thing: Make your program a [mcve]. It really does help. Another: Divide your programs into subgroups. Is everything a problem in this exercise?

Comment: First of all your ode is invalid C++, since standard C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use `std::vector` instead. Also what is the problem with the code you show? For some specific input, what is the expected and actual output? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also please take some time to learn how to use a *debugger*. A debugger is a crucial tool in any programmers toolbox, and knowledge of one and how to use one to step through code statement by statement while monitoring variable and their values, is something any programmer needs to know.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<E;i++) graph[list.u][list.v] = list.w; graph[list.v][list.u] = list.w;` -- You are missing `{ }` for that `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what you need to do is find the shortest path from the airport to the destination, then add 60 to all of the edges in that path, then perform dijkstra's algorithm again starting from your house and going to the office. There's probably a more efficient way to do it in one pass, but that'll get you started.